# Smooth print code in sublime text 2/3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have one question about greatful text editor sublime text.

In MS Word 2013 appeared a nice feature - smooth text print and smooth scrolling.

How does know - is there that feature in Sublime text 2 or 3? May by there is a special plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: You should define smooth text print and smooth scrolling.

Comment: Can you tell, how should I do it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

As the "Settings - Default" comment explains about smooth scrolling:

```
// Set to 0 to disable smooth scrolling. Set to a value between 0 and 1 to
// scroll slower, or set to larger than 1 to scroll faster
"scroll_speed": 1.0,
```

So in your user settings (from the preference menu "Settings - User") set the "scroll_speed" key to something smaller than 1, but larger than 0 (which disables smooth scrolling). If you have an empty settings file, then it would then look something like:

```
{
    "scroll_speed": 0.2,
}
```